# Vb.Net Excel automation row select event

Tags: .net, excel, automation

In a VB.Net Windows app I create an Excel object thru early binding and populate the spreadsheet with rows returned from SQL.

The intent is to allow the user to select 1 or more rows from the spreadsheet, capture the select event, and then retrieve all the data from the selected rows for further processing. I know this would be simple if I populated a datagridview with the SQL data but the users insist on Excel.

Although I have searched I haven't been able to discover whether capturing the select event in .Net is possible.

If it is possible, please show me how or give me a link to a good article on this topic. If not, please let me know too.

Thank you!

---

Thanks for the run-down, Mike. I will do some more research, now that I have a good basis to start with. My users will be doing a variety of things in the spreadsheet: 1) selecting rows for further processing (routed operations); may be non-contiguous 2) adding rows if the the operation doesn't appear in the input (unrouted operations) and then selecting them. 3) possibly adding column data (I'd like to restrict this function but the User is boss....)

I will experiment but can you tell me how to discriminate between a row selection and a column selection; i.e. selection changes I want to respond to and ones I don't?

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for the "SelectionChange" event. There are three related events for this: `Worksheet.SelectionChange`, `Workbook.SheetSelectionChange`, and `Application.SheetSelectionChange`.

I think that for your purposes, using `Worksheet.SelectionChange` is probably what you would want, since you already know which worksheet in which you are interested, but here's an example using all three as an example:

```
Public Class ExcelEventHandlingClass
    Dim WithEvents xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim WithEvents myWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim WithEvents myWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet

    Sub New()
        xlApp = New Excel.Application
        xlApp.Visible = True

        myWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
        myWorksheet = CType(myWorkbook.Worksheets.Add, Excel.Worksheet)
    End Sub

    Private Sub xlApp_SheetSelectionChange( _
        ByVal Sh As Object, _
        ByVal Target As Excel.Range) _
        Handles xlApp.SheetSelectionChange

        MessageBox.Show( _
            "xlApp_SheetSelectionChange: " & _
            Target.Address(External:=True) & " was selected")
    End Sub

    Private Sub myWorkbook_SheetSelectionChange( _
        ByVal Sh As Object, _
        ByVal Target As Excel.Range) _
        Handles myWorkbook.SheetSelectionChange

        MessageBox.Show( _
            "myWorkbook_SheetSelectionChange: " & _
            Target.Address(External:=True) & " was selected")
    End Sub

    Private Sub myWorksheet_SelectionChange( _
        ByVal Target As Excel.Range) _
        Handles myWorksheet.SelectionChange

        MessageBox.Show( _
            "myWorksheet_SelectionChange: " & _
            Target.Address(External:=True) & " was selected")
    End Sub
End Class
```

You can run the above as follows:

```
Dim o As ExcelEventHandlingClass

Private Sub StartExample()
    o = New ExcelEventHandlingClass
End Sub
```

In this example, if you change the selection on the active worksheet, then all three event handlers fire and you get 3 message boxes. It's a bit annoying, lol, but it proves the point.

Of course you don't have to use `WithEvents` to hook up your event handlers, you could use AddHandler instead:

```
AddHandler xlApp.SheetSelectionChange, AddressOf xlApp_SheetSelectionChange
AddHandler myWorkbook.SheetSelectionChange, AddressOf myWorkbook_SheetSelectionChange
AddHandler myWorksheet.SelectionChange, AddressOf myWorksheet_SelectionChange
```

Once your handler has been called, it can extract values using automation. You could use the `Range.Value` property to get the values from a single cell, or return a 2 dimensional range of values from a multi-cell range. Of course you could just run SQL again, once you know which Row(s) you want, based on the selection, but I just thought I'd point out that you can extract the cell values directly.

Hope this helps!

Mike

**Edit: Update to Melody's Reply**

> "Thank you so much for helping, Mike!"

No problem. :-)

> "I need to get into the nitty-gritty
>   of the Target.Address(External:=True)
>   bit. I assume the target contains info
>   on what was selected? Can you provide
>   more info? Does it encapsulate a row
>   number or numbers of the rows
>   selected? Does it contain an index or
>   item property that can be used to get
>   at the column values? Does the
>   External=True argument just say this
>   is coming from non-managed code, or is
>   my assumption incorrect?"

That was just an example to show how to report the address of the Range that was selected. Let's look at the method signature for the Worksheet.SelectionChange event handler:

```
Private Sub myWorksheet_SelectionChange( _
    ByVal Target As Excel.Range) _
    Handles myWorksheet.SelectionChange

   ' Your code goes here...

End Sub
```

The event has one argument, which is the `Target As Excel.Range` argument. (The `Application.SheetSelectionChange` and `Workbook.SheetSelectionChange` events have a second argument stating on which worksheet the selection change occurred, but in the case of the `Worksheet.Selection` change event we already know on which worksheet the selection change occurred, so the parameter is omitted.)

The key is that you can make use of the  `Target As Excel.Range` argument to determine what you want. To get the local address, which includes the Range address, but not the worksheet address (E.g. "A1:C3"):

```
Dim localAddress As String = Target.Address
```

To get the full path address (e.g. "[Book1.xls]Sheet1!A1:C3"):

```
Dim localAddress As String = Target.Address(External:=True)
```

To get the number of rows selected:

```
Dim numRows As Integer = Target.Rows.Count
```

To get the Row Index on the worksheet (remember: Excel workshets use Base 1 addressing!) for the top row of the range:

```
Dim topRowIndex As Integer = Target.Row
```

To get the row index for the last row:

```
Dim lastRowIndex As Integer = Target.Rows(Target.Rows.Count).Row
```

These are just some examples. You'll have to make use of the Excel VBA help files (or Google) to get more information on the members of the Range class.

> Due to the holiday I may not be able
>   to respond to you right away, but I am
>   grateful for the help.

Slacker. Just kidding, have a great weekend. :-)

Comment: Where was this when I had this problem back in July ;)

A great answer none the less!

Comment: @Chris: LOL, this question was too months too late, I guess. You've been struggling with this since July? You should have posted the question yourself!

Comment: Nice post! I am new to Events handling with .NET and that was the best intro I could find! One questions not precisely on the topic but why do you use a `CType` in `myWorksheet = CType(myWorkbook.Worksheets.Add, Excel.Worksheet)`? Does this have something do to with the fact that the `.Sheets Collection` may contain `Worksheets` as well as `Charts`?